# Совместимость raid контроллеров

Tags: controller, железо, raid

Я настроил RAID-5 из 4-х дисков на железном RAID контроллере 3ware 9650SE-4lpml.
Если вдруг сам контроллер выйдет из строя (но диски будут в порядке), смогу ли я подключить свой уже собранный RAID массив к любому другому контроллеру и дальше использовать его или же мне нужен будет контроллер именно этой марки/модели?

Answer (score 0):

С большой долей вероятности диски будут работать только на аналогичном контроллере, всё зависит по большей части от прошивки.
Но можно собрать эти диски в рабочий том с помощью специального софта.